# @component spring annotation in wicket project?

Tags: java, spring, wicket-1.6

I am very new to SO,I have working on the task where Load environment configurations and properties  according to the environment like (dev,prod,test),I have been successfully  achieved database configuration on DAO level by using `<beans profile="profile.name">`. In front end side I have to get properties file according to the environment so I have the different files. to call that i have tried the below code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class PropertiesUtility {
    @Value("${mount.images.webpath}")
    private String imagePath;

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PropertiesUtility{" +
                "imagePath='" + imagePath + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My context.xml configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <beans profile="dev">
            <context:property-placeholder  location="classpath:properties/pharmisa_web_conf.properties"
                                           ignore-unresolvable="true" />

        </beans>
        <beans profile="test">
            <context:property-placeholder  location="classpath:properties/pharmisa_web_test_conf.properties"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" />

        </beans>
```

**Calling PropertiesUtility:**

```
public class URLUtility {
    @SpringBean //even @Autowired also not working
   static PropertiesUtility propertiesUtility;
    public static String getCompanyLogoUrl(int id) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(getImagePath());
        boolean isEndWithSlash=PharmisaStringUtils.endsWith(getImagePath(),"/");
        if (!isEndWithSlash){
            sb.append("/");
        }
        sb.append(id);
        sb.append("/");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static final String getImagePath() {

        return propertiesUtility.getImagePath().trim();
    }

}
```

**SpringJunitTest**

> Test working perfectly

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/pharmisa_web-context.xml"})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
public class CompanyServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    PropertiesUtility propertiUtility;

    @Test
    public void testAppProperties() {
        System.out.println(propertiUtility.getImagePath());
    }

}
```

When i tried to inject  PropertiesUtility class in wicket page  .I am not getting the value of the properties. because it is not injected. I have aware of `@SpringBean` in wicket but even though it is not working.

Is there anyway to get the value any alternative welcomes.

For your further i have followed the link

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/load-environment-configurations-and-properties-with-spring-example/

Comment: How do you inject PropertiesUtility in Wicket ? You missed to show us the most important part.

Comment: In addition to what Martin-g has asked, I would also suggest to run some Spring Test (using TESTNG for example) and AutoWire your Component to see if you are actually getting the file path from the spring component itself without UI.

Comment: @martin-g I have tried with Autowired and SpringBean also but is not working

Comment: @Mihir test working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

`URLUtility` should be a Spring bean if you want `@Component` or `@Autowire` to work.

`@SrpingBean` works automatically only in Wicket components. In anything else you need to "ask for injection" explicitly with `Injector.get().inject(this)`.